# REACTJS modify column data in CSV

Tags: reactjs

I get a csv with multiple columns from the backend, but I would like to change the data in a column before exporting this csv as a report.
Today I am using the react-csv library to export the report.

The column I want to modify is the Type. Currently she returns the values ​​Product and Service. Instead of displaying Product I would like to display New Product and instead of Service I would like to display Used Product

report:

```
"Title","Type","Advertiser","Category"
"2 plots of 15x35 - R $ 15,000.00 each","product","LUIZ FABIANO DE OLIVEIRA0","Properties"
"3 Industrial machines","service","GISELE SANTANA","services"
```

code:

```
export default function exem() {
    const [dataExport, setDataExport] = React.useState([]);

    function getCSV() {
        request
            .get(urlGetCSV() + `&page=${page}`)
            .text()
            .then(response => {
                setDataExport(response)
            });
    }
    return (
        <>
            <CSVLink
                data={dataExport}
                filename={`report-${new Date().toLocaleString()}.csv`}
                onClick={getCSV}
            >
                <Button>
                    Report
                  <Button.Icon>
                        <ReportIcon />
                    </Button.Icon>
                </Button>
            </CSVLink>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what `console.log(response);` gives you? because the answer will depend on the format you are getting in `response`.

Answer (score 0):

If response is an array you could remap it before calling setDataExport:

```js
const typeMappings = {
  'product': 'New Product',
  'service': 'Used Product'
}
```

```js
.then(response => {
  // find the "Type" column
  const headers = response[0]; // assumes headers in the first row
  const typeColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Type'); // index of the column with 'Type' header

  response.forEach(item => { // iterate over each row
    // get the type from the row
    const originalType = item[typeColumnIndex];

    // replace it with the corresponding mapping.
    // if no mapping exists, leave the original value.
    item[typeColumnIndex] = typeMappings[originalType] || originalType;
  })

  setDataExport(response)
});
```

Comment: I reproduced your answer, but I'm getting the error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.forEach is not a function

Comment: My example assumes `response` is an array of rows. If your API returns something else, adjust the code accordingly.